# Angularjs and Nodejs express

Tags: express

I'm trying to upload images through angularjs (client side) and Nodejs express (server side). I perfer not to use forms because my company does not work with it.

this is part of my controller-

```
$scope.uploadPhotoToServer = function () {
    console.log('will upload to album ' + this.albumName + ' file ' + this.userPhoto);


    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", this.userPhoto);
    fd.append("album", this.albumName);

    $http.post('/upload', fd, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
      transformRequest: angular.identity
    });
}]);
```

I wish if you could explain to me how this works and how I could continue
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to know, or what part you don't understand, but this basically just creates a $scope member function that adds the userPhoto and albumName to the FormData object (fd), which represents the form.The function then sends that object to the server using $http. You can think of the $http as a typical ajax command that just sends data to the server. (It actually uses the same XMLhttpRequest object that ajax does.

if you need it, here is a reference to the FormData() being used:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData